# How do I add the elements of a file to a second one as columns using Perl?

Tags: perl

1st file called W.txt and the 2sd is Rs.txt

W.txt:

```
ID  age gender  bmi status  
CAD7    57  F   28.80   0
CAD9    74  F   29.26   1
CAD11   53  M   NA  1
CAD12   61  M   27.16   1
CAD14   77  M   29.28   1
CAD17   74  M   35.99   1
CAD18   81  F   28.12   1
CAD24   73  M   22.23   1
```

Rs.txt:

```
2   2   2   
2   2   2   
2   0   2   
2   2   2   
1   2   2   
1   2   2   
1   2   2   
1   2   2
```

so the output must be like this

```
CAD7    57  F   28.80   0   2   2   2   
CAD9    74  F   29.26   1   2   2   2
CAD11   53  M   NA  1   1   2   2
```

Comment: You'll have to write a program. Give it a try and if you have problems, post them here and perhaps we can help you.

Comment: 1) It's Perl, not PERL. 2) No attempt at solving the problem has been shown. Please help us help you by following the community guidelines.

Comment: 3) It is unclear how you want to add data.

Comment: Why isn't it `CAD11   53  M   NA  1   2   0   2`?

Answer (score 23):

I think you're trying to merge two files that have corresponding records. I've seen this problem several times with legacy systems where different data come from different sources. You have to be sure that all the records line up (e.g. there's not an addition or deletion in one list), but let's assume that's true for now.

This is a simple task if you're used to dealing with line-oriented files (and not everything in the universe is). You read one line from each file, remove the line ending, concatenate the two lines, and output the result to a third file (although I use standard output in this case):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; # a programming aid to keep us honest

# open each file
open my $W, '<', 'W.txt' or die "Could not open W.txt: $!";
open my $Rs, '<', 'Rs.txt' or die "Could not open Rs.txt: $!";

# read the header of W.txt and ignore it
# this syncs the positions in the file
readline( $W );

while( 1 ) { # keep going until something else stops us
    # read a line for each file
    my $W_line  = readline( $W  );
    my $Rs_line = readline( $Rs );

    # stop if we ran out of lines from one of the files
    last unless( defined $W_line and defined $Rs_line );

    # remove the line ending from the W line
    # leave the line ending on the Rs line because we'll use it
    chomp( $W_line );

    # output the combined line with a space between them
    print $W_line, ' ', $Rs_line;
    }
```

I've added plenty of code comments here. When I'm working with something I'm not sure about, I often sketch out the process I want in comments then fill in the code to perform those bits. This is roughly the process you might take if you were doing this by hand. Remember, programming is automating the boring tasks that would take us a long time to do, so the steps are often the same. Indeed, sometimes I do things by hand first to figure out the problems in the process.

But, the real trick in programming is knowing when you don't need to program at all. You want to merge two files. There's a program for that:

```
% paste W.txt Rs.txt
```

There's a problem with that header line in *W.txt*. The easiest thing might be to simply copy the file and remove that one line. If you don't have to do this again, little manual interventions can save you quite a bit of work:

```
% paste W-noheader.txt Rs.txt
```

Alternatively, you could add a dummy line to *Rs.txt* so it has a header too. You might be able to get the source of that data to add that. It would be much nicer to have the column headings for the new values. Another programming trick is the application of beer. It lubricates many problems.

If you aren't on a machine that has `paste` (I'm not looking at you, Windows, but seriously I am), there's a fabulous project called the [Perl Power Tools](http://perlpowertools.com) that recreates the tools in Perl, meaning that you can use them anywhere that you have a `perl`, but also that you can look at the source to see how they do it. You can take a tool that is close to what you want and modify it slightly for your local purpose. There's nothing special about Perl here. If you find something close in any language, go with that. The trick is to get work done.

But, lets assume that you can neither hand edit the file to remove the header (perhaps because this has to be repeatable) nor can you change the source to add a header. You need to sync the files starting at different lines. I thought that `paste` should handle this, but no version I've found does, and I also thought a tricky application of `tail` or `head` does. Maybe a better Unix guru can provide a command line.

---

And a Unix guru has provided such a command line using sub-processes. [This is from Rhombold on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/2exuxl/how_do_i_add_the_elements_of_a_file_to_a_second/ck46rvl):

*To paste file1 with the contents of file2 minus the first line you can do:*

```
$ paste file1 <(tail -n +2 file2) >output
```

You can generalize this to any number of inputs:

```
$ paste <(tail -n +10 file1) <(tail -n +3 file2) <(tail -n +7 file3) >output
```

---

I've already given you the answer to get your task done, so now I'm going to go off into the wilds on this problem. I want an improved paste that lets me specify the starting line for each file. First, I need to know how I want to specify that. `paste` can work with two *or more* files, so I want to be able to do that too. I need to be able to specify starting line numbers for each file. I could do something like this, where I have a list of starting line numbers in the same order as the files I specify. The comma isn't an argument separator in this case:

```
% epaste -l 1,2,3 file1 file2 file3
```

I don't like that because the line numbers are separated from the files; it seems dirty to me. I'd rather keep them together. If I have to build up this command line from another program, I don't want to track the line numbers and wait until the end of each input to know how to output the command. Instead, I'll do something that also feels slightly dirty by allowing the filename to end in "=N" to specify the starting line:

```
% epaste file1=1 file2=37 file3
```

This has a problem for files with an `=` in the name, but life it tough.

Looking at the source for the [Perl Power Tools version of `paste`](http://api.metacpan.org/source/CWEST/ppt-0.14/bin/paste), I see there's really only one place I need to change. As it opens the files, I need to "fast forward" the files to the right starting line. The current code has this:

```
for $i (0..$#ARGV) {
    $fh[$i] = "F$i";
    open($fh[$i], $ARGV[$i]) or die "$0: cannot open $ARGV[$i]";
}
```

But I need to change it to parse the filenames to look for starting line numbers then move to that line number.

```
for $i (0..$#ARGV) {
    $fh[$i] = "F$i";
    my( $name, $line ) = $ARGV[$i] =~ /(.*?) (?: = ([0-9]+) )? \z/x;
    open($fh[$i], $name) or die "$0: cannot open $name";
    if( defined $line ) {
        tell( $fh[$i] );
        readline( $fh[$i] ) while $. < $line - 1
    }
}
```

There are a few interesting things to note here. In the line to get the file name, I have this match:

```
$ARGV[$i] =~ /(.*?) (?: = ([0-9]+) )? \z/x;
```

I have a non-greedy match for any character except a newline, `(.*?)` followed by an option portion to look for an equal sign followed by a series of decimal digits `(?: = ([0-9]+) )?`, but only at the end `\z`. The `/x` let's me spread that out by making whitespace in the pattern insignificant.

If I match something, `$line` has a value. If I don't, `$line` has undef. I only need to fast forward if there's something in `$line`. I use [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) to check for that.

```
    if( defined $line ) {
        ...
    }
```

Inside that `if`, I need to stop at the right line number. If I want to start at line 37, I need to read and discard 36 lines. That's one less than the number I specified.

To do this, I can look at `$.`, the current line number of the mostly recently read file (documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Note that "most recently read". I haven't read the file I'm working with, but I can use [tell](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) to change `$.` to my just opened filehandle without reading data:

```
        tell( $fh[$i] );
        readline( $fh[$i] ) while $. < $line - 1
```

---

*James at [blogs.perl.org](http://blogs.perl.org/) comments that I could have [used the filehandle as an object](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2014/08/i-learn-something-about-tell-then-abuse-it.html#comment-1416219) and avoid the special variable altogether:*

```
... $fh->input_line_number < $line - 1
```

*That's my Perl 4 showing through. Note that you might have to include `use FileHandle` in code for v5.12 and earlier since this wasn't added as a default until v5.14.*

---

And that's it, almost. I don't look at the rest of the program and the tricky things it's doing to handle the other features of `paste`, such as changing the separator.

To keep supporting the special filename `-` as a name for standard input, I need to adjust the options processing a bit so it doesn't think `=` is an option (which I don't show here):

```
% epaste -=3 W.txt
```

I wish I could specify `-` with a starting line number multiple times, but those all step on each other because they use the same data. I can specify multiple files at the same time (if your filesystem allows simultaneous file reads):

```
% epaste animals.txt=2 animals.txt=6 animals.txt=4
```

This means your solution boils down to:

```
% epaste W.txt=2 Rs.txt
```

I've made an [epaste gist](https://gist.github.com/8af92ac34c36f100b1dc.git) for those who want the file or have corrections to fix mistakes that I've made.

And, that's the final programming trick of the day: Get someone else to write the program. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's really bad manners to ask just for the code!

You can do that by reading the whole file into a string and split the string by `"\n"`, pushing it into an array, and print each element like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open W_FILE, "./W.txt" or die $!;
open R_FILE, "./R.txt" or die $!;
my $w_content;
my $r_content;

while(<W_FILE>) {
  $w_content .= $_;
}
close(W_FILE);
while(<R_FILE>) {
  $r_content .= $_;
}
close(R_FILE);

my @w_array = split(/\n/, $w_content);
my @r_array = split(/\n/, $r_content);

my $i;
for($i = 0; $i < $#w_array; $i ++) {
  print $w_array[$i+1]." ".$r_array[$i]."\n";
}
```

Comment: You just rewarded bad manners, so there's no reason now why the OP won't do this again.

Comment: Indeed. No one should get the answer because one person had bad manners. There's a reason this isn't a reply-by-email service :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the index values are unique and the data fits in memory, I'd just use a hash of arrays

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_hash_ref;  #store the data here

open (my $w_fh, "<", "W.txt") or die $!;

#skip title line
my $line = <$w_fh>;

while ($line = <$w_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @cols = split ("\t", $line);
    my $key = shift (@cols);
    $data_hash_ref -> {$key} = \@cols;
}
close $w_fh;

open (my $rs_fh, "<", "Rs.txt") or die $!;

while ($line = <$Rs_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @cols = split ("\t", $line);
    my $key = shift (@cols);

    #You probably want to check if the key exists first and handle it if it doesn't,
    #but I'm skipping that here

    push (@{$data_hash_ref -> {$key}}, @cols);
}
close $rs_fh;

#print it out
open (my $out_fh, ">", "merged.txt") or die $!;

foreach my $key (sort keys %$data_hash_ref) {
    my $row = join ("\t", @{$data_hash_ref -> {$key}})
    print $out_fh "$key\t$row\n";
}
close $out_fh;
```

Not as elegant as some solutions, but easy to follow if you understand perl referencing/dereferencing, and more importantly, easy to manipulate if you want to do anything else with the data besides printing it out.

Comment: It's even easier if you don't use a data structure. :)

Comment: This also has the disadvantage of losing data if you don't know that the first column has unique values.